# Understanding defaultdict behavior with a list default

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to understand the following code:

```
from collections import defaultdict

dd_pair = defaultdict(lambda: [0, 0])
dd_pair[2][1] = 1                       # now dd_pair contains {2: [0,1]}
```

I understand `defaultdict` defaults to a list of two elements here. But how is the result ending up to be `{2: [0,1]}`

Comment: Umm ... because you're setting the second element to be `1`?  A default dict factories up a new value when you access a new key ... and then places it into the underlying dict .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`dd_pair[2]` is returning a reference to a freshly created `list` with the value `[0, 0]`. Ignore the `defaultdict` itself, and see how it works with a `list` like that:

```
>>> mylist = [0, 0]
>>> mylist[1] = 1
>>> mylist
[0, 1]
```

The `defaultdict` is just dynamically creating a `list` like `mylist` each time you access a heretofore unaccessed key, storing it as the value of the requested key, and returning a reference to it. By adding `[1]` you do an index assignment to that `list`, and since it's the same `list` reference that was stored and returned, modifying one modifies the other.